# Not much activity after 24 hours

Tags: fermentation, stuck-fermentation, krausen

Yesterday I brewed up a batch of an american brown ale. 24 hours after pitching, it doesn't to look to be moving so well. There are hints of a krausen, but not as much as there should be. I don't see any of the nice churning that there should be. There really is no airlock activity (although I have quite a bit of head space, doing a half batch into a 5 gallon carboy) Here is my plan, let me know if I am thinking the wrong things:

Currently the temp is about 65, I was going to let it warm up a few degrees and see if I get some more activity by this evening. If not, I was going to re-hydrate some more S-05 and throw that in there. I was not going  to re-aerate it, as there is a small krausen, meaning I probably should add oxygen at this point.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd leave it overnight and give it more chance to work. Just because there is no activity in the airlock does not mean it's not fermenting

Comment: Agreed. I have had some beers take 48 hours before activity was noticeable in the airlock. And that's with a full 5 gallon batch.